# How to force end Response() ExpressJS , In easy way? (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, express

How can I achieve this. In an easy way in ExpressJS?

```
App.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  await something.catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json("something wrong")
  })

  if (res.headersSent) return;
  res.json("2st response");
});
```

Can I just call res.json() two time then express automatically understand to end response and not to send second response ? without of using middleware to check that response already send or not!

Answer (score 1):

In your logic here with `await`, it's easier to just use `try/catch` instead of `.catch()` and that makes the flow a lot easier:

```
App.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
      await something;
  } catch(err) {
      res.status(500).json("something wrong");
      return;
  });

  res.json("2st response");
});
```

In general, you don't mix `await` with `.catch()` and partly for this reason because using `await` and `try/catch` makes code flow like this simpler since you directly return from the outer function in the `try/catch(err)` statement, but you cannot do that in the `.catch()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return` before `res.send`. This way it will send a response and exit the function.

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  return res.send("1st responce");

  // Unreachable code
  if(res.headersSent) return;
  res.json("2st responce")
})
```

Comment: This is not what I asked .what if there is an function.Then how can you use **Return**?

Comment: Understand the concept  before answer.